# Parsing json from api.facebook.com

Tags: java, facebook, json, facebook-graph-api

How can I parse the json [from this link](https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=JSON&query=select%20comments%20from%20comment%20where%20object_id%20in%20%28select%20comments_fbid%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url%20=%27http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/%27%29&pretty=1) using java (for a stand alone java application)? I tried gson & Jackson libraries, but they seem to have problems as the formatting of this json appears different.

How do you do it?

Given the popularity of facebook, I was hoping to find some jars/lib that can do this already. Recommendations with examples are most welcome. Thanks much.

**Response.java**

```
public class Response{
private List<Comments> commentslist;

public List<Comments> getCommentsList() {
    return commentslist;
}

public void setCommentsList(List<Comments> commentslist) {
    this.commentslist = commentslist;
}
}
```

**Comments.java**

```
public class Comments{
private Number count;
private List<Data> data;

public Number getCount(){
    return this.count;
}
public void setCount(Number count){
    this.count = count;
}
public List<Data> getData(){
    return this.data;
}
public void setData(List<Data> data){
    this.data = data;
}
}
```

**From.java**

```
public class From{
    private Number id;
private String name;

public Number getId(){
    return this.id;
}
public void setId(Number id){
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName(){
    return this.name;
}
public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

**Data.java**

```
public class Data{
private Number created_time;
private From from;
private Number id;
private String message;

public Number getCreated_time(){
    return this.created_time;
}
public void setCreated_time(Number created_time){
    this.created_time = created_time;
}
public From getFrom(){
    return this.from;
}
public void setFrom(From from){
    this.from = from;
}
public Number getId(){
    return this.id;
}
public void setId(Number id){
    this.id = id;
}
public String getMessage(){
    return this.message;
}
public void setMessage(String message){
    this.message = message;
}
}
```

**Failed Converstion Attempt using gson**

```
Response response = gson.fromJson(contents, Response.class); //contents is json string
System.out.println(response.getCommentsList()); // comes back as null
```

If json is normal, is something wrong with my java models?

Comment: Your link looks like normal JSON. If it's not working, I would think that your implementation is incorrect. Without looking at your code, we can't tell.

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA Added code for reference. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not familier with Gson, but is this suppose to use reflection to parse the JSON string?

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA Yes thats correct. I do not have a requirement to use gson. I am completely open to any other workable suggestions.

Comment: Can you please let me know what your solution is? If it is any of below, please check it as THE answer, otherwhise, provide with your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to deserialize the JSON response(which is an array of objects) into an object(Response) with a list(commentList) of comments(Comments). There is a type/structure mismatch and GSON won't be able to deserialize that.

Try doing something like:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<Response>>(){}.getType();
List<Comments> commentList = gson.fromJson(yourJsonString, collectionType);
```

And change your Response object into:

```
public class Response{
  private Comments comments;

  public Comments getComments() {
      return comments;
  }

  public void setComments( Comments comments) {
      this.comments= comments;
  }
}
```

The json from fb is a list of response(anonymous) objects that has 1 field called comments. Comments, despite the name, is actually an object.

Comment: I get this error when I try that. Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2.

Comment: Hmm, can you try doing it the other way around. Populate your POJO data model and serialize it into json and see if it generates a similar structure as the one being returned by facebook?

Comment: The json is different than the facebook json - that was my initial gut feeling. I am surprised there is no library to parse these comments directly.

{"comments":[{"count":2,"data":[{"created_time":1111111111,"from":{"id":12,"name":"User1"},"id":1234,"message":"Form response 1"},{"created_time":1431111111,"from":{"id":12,"name":"User2"},"id":1235,"message":"Form response 2"}]},{"count":2,"data":[{"created_time":1111111111,"from":{"id":12,"name":"User1"},"id":1234,"message":"Form response 1"},{"created_time":1431111111,"from":{"id":12,"name":"User2"},"id":1235,"message":"Form response 2"}]}]}

Answer (score 0):

The JSON [validates](http://jsonlint.com/) fine. The top container in that JSON is an array, not an object. Try:

```
List<Response> responses = gson.fromJson( contents, Response.class );
System.out.println(responses[0].getCommentsList());
```

Comment: @ThinkingStuff After fixing the syntax, I ended up with thie error: Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2